# Summing unknown number of vectors

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of type double & say of size 2000 x 2. The number of columns in the matrix can vary from 2 to about 20. The number of rows will also vary. What I would like to do is sum the all the columns in the matrix into a vector. How can I do this with out looping through all the columns?

I have tried the line below, however that return a 2 x 1 vector if there are two columns or a 3 x 1 vector if there is three columns etc. So its just taking the sum of the total column.

```
result_vec = sum(my_matrix(:, 1:end))


 Column 1       Column 2        Column 3          Result Vector
 5              3               2                 10   
 3              11              4                 18 
 9              6               7                 22
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to calculate? row sum? column sum? sum?

Comment: You are allowed to explore the [documentation on sum](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) a bit more because the solution is right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the row sum, you have to summarize over the second dimension.

`sum(my_matrix,2)`